# How to use @autoclosure parameter in async block in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures

I would like to call an @autoclosure parameter inside `dispatch_async` block.

```
func myFunc(@autoclosure condition: () -> Bool) {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    if condition() {
      println("Condition is true")
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error.

> Closure use of @noescape parameter may allow it to escape.

Is it possible to call @autoclosure parameter asynchronously?

Tested in Xcode 6.4 (6E23).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, so long as you declare them `@autoclosure(escaping)`:

> Declarations with the `autoclosure` attribute imply `noescape` as well, except when passed the optional attribute `escaping`.

So this should do it:

```
func myFunc(@autoclosure(escaping) condition: () -> Bool) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        if condition() {
            println("Condition is true")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it works it's great but could this be dangerous for user using this api? If it's a closure and let's say it asynchronous we know we have to use `[weak self]` but if it is an escaping autoclosure user won't use `[weak self]` ?

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Though if you do reference `self` implicitly, you’ll get a warning by the compiler that you need to reference `self` explicitly to acknowledge the capture (same as with a closure expression)

Comment: And of course bear in mind there’s nothing stopping you calling `myFunc` with an explicit closure as well: `myFunc { [weak self] in self?.p ?? false }`

Comment: it's neat that the compiler let us know about self capture sadly [weak self] isn't possible when using short notation `myFunc(true)`, also I am unable to use `myFunc { [weak self] in self?.p ?? false }`

Comment: instead have to do something like this: `myApiCall ({ [weak self] in self?.loading = false }())`, triggering a segfault on compile

Comment: funny because [Apple Swift blog](https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4) has this as per example `assert({ someExpensiveComputation() != 42 })`

Comment: `myFunc(true)` doesn’t capture anything.  And `myFunc(someLocalVar)` is usually fine too, especially if its a value type.  But yeah, I’d be wary of `@autoclosure` in general except for simple stuff like short-circuiting

Answer (score 1):

Updating the answer from Airspeed Velocity, you can pass weak self directly into escaping autoclosure.

```
var boolValue: Bool = true

func myFunc(condition: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Bool?) {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        if let condition = condition() {
            print("Condition is \(condition ? "true" : "false")")
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    weak var weakSelf = self
    myFunc(condition: weakSelf?.boolValue)
}
```